# Why is pip reporting dependencies conflicts even though there are none?

Tags: python, numpy, build, pip, pip-tools

`pip` is reporting dependencies conflicts when there are none:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    apache-beam[gcp] 2.39.0 depends on numpy<1.23.0 and >=1.14.3
    tensorflow-utils 0.0.18.dev1 depends on numpy==1.22.4
```

`tensorflow-utils==0.0.18.dev1` is my own package. The boundaries in the conflict specify that numpy must be `>=1.14.3` and `<1.23` for `apache-beam[gcp]`, which my `numpy==1.22.4` version satisfies.

Environment details:

```
root@6b7ea6e22c5a:/# python3 -V
Python 3.7.10

root@6b7ea6e22c5a:/# python3 -m pip -V
pip 21.2.2 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip-compile --resolver backtracking`?

Answer (score 0):

It could be cached dependency information: It's possible that pip has cached outdated or conflicting dependency information. You can try clearing the pip cache `pip cache purge`

Comment: If this is a guess, then it doesn't belong as an answer.  The question is now marked as "answered", making it less likely that other people will come along and answer it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).